# Find maximal domain and range

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

$f\left( x,y\right) = \ln \left( 1-x^{2}-y^{2}\right)$

I have noticed that

$1-x^{2}-y^{2}\gt 0$

But from here I am unsure

Thanks

Comment: Your inequality is not correct as written...

Comment: Be careful, $ln(0)$ is not defined. The inequality is with the '>' symbol.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

Logarithm takes arguments which are positive. So you want $1-x^2-y^2 > 0$.
This is interior of the unit circle.

For range observe that log is an increasing function, therefore try to focus on the center of your domain and see what happens as you go towards the circumference of the unit circle.